# Find the area of the following triangle T

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find the area of the following triangle T given that the vertices of T are A(5,6,2), B(7,16,4), and C(6,7,3).

Answer (score 4):

## METHOD 1:

Using distance formula, $D = \sqrt{(x-x')^2+(y-y')^2+(z-z')^2}$

find $c = AB,  \ b = CA , \ c = AB$

and $s= \frac{a+b+c}{2}$

Use Heron's formula,

> $$A = \sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}$$

## METHOD 2:

Let $\vec{p} = \vec{AB}$ and $\vec{q} = \vec{AC}$

then area of the triangle is,

> $$A = \frac{1}{2}||\vec{p}\times\vec{q}||$$

Comment: So would the correct answer be the square root of 128?

Comment: Sorry I saw your comment just now. $\sqrt{128}$ is the area of parallelogram. The area of the triangle is just its half i.e, $\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{128}$